# Hover tool does not display tooltip when associated with segment glyphs

Tags: python, bokeh, segment

I've checked many answers to similar questions but none are related. For me, the hover tool is enabled but no matter how far in I zoom to isolate the item from all others (no overlapping) the tool tip never displays.  Now I have this working on another app using segment glyph but line_width=12 (x) and as one zooms in the height of the segment expands (y) and eventually the tool tip is presented.  Where it is not working, line_width=1 (lots of data), the segment is a horizontal line (same y value for y0, y1).  I thought it might be related to line_width being too small.  But even when it's value is set very large (20) and zoom in and eliminate all overlapping no tool tip is presented.
Here is my test code:

```
from bokeh.io import output_file
from bokeh.models.ranges import Range1d
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models.tools import HoverTool
import random

def build_test_data(dataSeries2gen, count2gen, series2gen):
    # test data
    vectorSeries = []
    if dataSeries2gen == "horizontal":
        # gen random seed numbers for X and Y but always use same Y
        for nSeries in range(0, series2gen):
            sameY = [random.randint(1, 4000) for y in range(4000)]
            randX1 = [random.randint(1, 51200) for x in range(51200)]
            randX2 = [random.randint(1, 51200) for x in range(51200)]
            nextSeries = []
            for nextSeed in range(1, count2gen):
                yIdx = random.randint(1, 3999)
                xIdx = random.randint(1, 51999)
                nextSegment = [randX1[xIdx], sameY[yIdx],\ 
                               randX2[xIdx], sameY[yIdx]]
                nextSeries.append(nextSegment)
            vectorSeries.append(nextSeries)
    else:
        for nSeries in range(0, series2gen):
            randY1 = [random.randint(1, 4000) for y in range(4000)]
            randY2 = [random.randint(1, 4000) for y in range(4000)]
            randX1 = [random.randint(1, 51200) for x in range(51200)]
            randX2 = [random.randint(1, 51200) for x in range(51200)]
            nextSeries = []
            for nextSeed in range(1, count2gen):
                nextSegment = [randX1[nextSeed], randY1[nextSeed],\
                              [randX2[nextSeed], randY2[nextSeed]]
                nextSeries.append(nextSegment)
            vectorSeries.append(nextSeries)

    plot_segments_withSource(vectorSeries)

def plot_segments_withSource(theData):

    colorPalette = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "orange"]

    output_file("test.html", mode='inline')
    xRange = Range1d(1, 51200)
    yRange = Range1d(1, 4000)

    p = figure(plot_width=700, plot_height=750, x_range=xRange,\
               y_range=yRange, output_backend="webgl")
    colorIdx = -1
    for nSeries in theData:
        colorIdx += 1
        color2use = colorPalette[colorIdx]
        x0 = []
        y0 = []
        x1 = []
        y1 = []
        for vPoints in nSeries:
            x0.append(vPoints[0])
            y0.append(vPoints[1])
            x1.append(vPoints[2])
            y1.append(vPoints[3])
        source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
            x0 = x0,
            y0 = y0,
            x1 = x1,
            y1 = y1
            )
        )
        p.segment(x0="01", y0="y0", x1="x1", y1="y1",\
                  line_color=color2use, source=source, line_width=1)

    # invert yAxis where 0 is at the top
    p.y_range = Range1d(4000, 0)

    hover = HoverTool()
    hover.tooltips = [("x0,y0", "$x0,$y0"),
                      ("x1,y1", "$x1,$y1")]
    hover.point_policy = "snap_to_data"
    hover.line_policy = "nearest"

    p.add_tools(hover)

    p.title.text = "This is a test"
    p.legend.location = "top_right"
    p.xaxis.axis_label = "Occurrences"
    p.yaxis.axis_label = "Time"

    show(p)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dataSeries2gen = "horizontal"
    count2gen = 100000
    series2gen = 2
    build_test_data(dataSeries2gen, count2gen, series2gen)
```

I need this to work for both presentation of the data and for setting up custom JavaScript (mouse click event) to do other things.  But if the hover tool doesn't identify what's the item, the click event will not likely fire either.

Thanks

Comment: Found on GitHub Issue #6704: Fix hover hittest on horizontal/vertical segments #6930 was resolved in release 0.12.10. my version of bokeh is 0.13.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues I found in your code:

1) There is definitely an issue with the segment hover that doesn’t work on an inverted axis (Y-axis in this case). This could be a Bokeh problem    (please check/submit an issue)

2) The tooltips syntax is incorrect. According to Bokeh documentation only the following syntax is allowed

```
:$index: index of hovered point in the data source
:$name: value of the ``name`` property of the hovered glyph renderer
:$x: x-coordinate under the cursor in data space
:$y: y-coordinate under the cursor in data space
:$sx: x-coordinate under the cursor in screen (canvas) space
:$sy: y-coordinate under the cursor in screen (canvas) space
:$color: color data from data source
```

So `$x0,$x1,$y0,$y1` are not understood by the HoverTool and cannot be used. I replaced them with `@x0,@y0,@x1,@y1` which are equivalent to `$x,$y` in case your cursor points at the start or at the end of a segment. I also added `("x,y", "$sx,$sy")` to show the screen coordinates under the cursor.

To have the hover tooltips displayed correctly I did a trick by hiding the original y-axis and inserting an extra inverted one. This works but actually doesn’t make sense since the axis is inverted but the y-range is not. Anyway, I hope it helps.

```
from bokeh.io import output_file
from bokeh.models.ranges import Range1d
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, LinearAxis
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models.tools import HoverTool
import random

def build_test_data(dataSeries2gen, count2gen, series2gen):
    # test data
    vectorSeries = []
    if dataSeries2gen == "horizontal":
        # gen random seed numbers for X and Y but always use same Y
        for nSeries in range(0, series2gen):
            sameY = [random.randint(1, 4000) for y in range(4000)]
            randX1 = [random.randint(1, 51200) for x in range(51200)]
            randX2 = [random.randint(1, 51200) for x in range(51200)]
            nextSeries = []
            for nextSeed in range(1, count2gen):
                yIdx = random.randint(1, 3999)
                xIdx = random.randint(1, 51199)
                nextSegment = [randX1[xIdx], sameY[yIdx], randX2[xIdx], sameY[yIdx]]
                nextSeries.append(nextSegment)
            vectorSeries.append(nextSeries)
    else:
        for nSeries in range(0, series2gen):
            randY1 = [random.randint(1, 4000) for y in range(4000)]
            randY2 = [random.randint(1, 4000) for y in range(4000)]
            randX1 = [random.randint(1, 51200) for x in range(51200)]
            randX2 = [random.randint(1, 51200) for x in range(51200)]
            nextSeries = []
            for nextSeed in range(1, count2gen):
                nextSegment = [randX1[nextSeed], randY1[nextSeed], randX2[nextSeed], randY2[nextSeed]]
                nextSeries.append(nextSegment)
            vectorSeries.append(nextSeries)
    plot_segments_withSource(vectorSeries)

def plot_segments_withSource(theData):
    colorPalette = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "orange"]
    output_file("test.html", mode = 'inline')
    p = figure(plot_width = 700, plot_height = 750, output_backend = "webgl", y_axis_location = None)
    colorIdx = -1
    for nSeries in theData:
        colorIdx += 1
        color2use = colorPalette[colorIdx]
        x0, y0, x1, y1 = [], [], [], []
        for vPoints in nSeries:
            x0.append(vPoints[0])
            y0.append(vPoints[1])
            x1.append(vPoints[2])
            y1.append(vPoints[3])
        source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x0 = x0,y0 = y0,x1 = x1,y1 = y1))
        p.segment(x0 = "x0", y0 = "y0", x1 = "x1", y1 = "y1", line_color = color2use, source = source, line_width = 1)

    # insert inverted extra yAxis where 0 is at the top
    p.extra_y_ranges = {"Time Extra Axis": Range1d(start = 4000, end = 0) }
    p.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name = "Time Extra Axis", axis_label = 'Time'), 'left')
    hover = HoverTool()
    hover.tooltips = [("x0,y0", "@x0,@y0"), ("x1,y1", "@x1,@y1"), ("x,y", "$sx,$sy")]
    hover.point_policy = "snap_to_data"
    hover.line_policy = "nearest"
    p.add_tools(hover)
    p.title.text = "This is a test"
    p.xaxis.axis_label = "Occurrences"
    p.yaxis.axis_label = "Time"
    show(p)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dataSeries2gen = "horizontal"
    count2gen = 10
    series2gen = 2
    build_test_data(dataSeries2gen, count2gen, series2gen)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Your right, thank.  However, is this a bug?  I need to have the inverted Y axis.  Is there another work-around.  I will also add that in my other app there is an inverted Y axis there as well and it works.

Comment: Perhaps there is a work-around with the tooltips syntax?

Comment: I pasted a modified code in my answer. Could you confirm it works for you?

Comment: Tony, thanks for the update. But no, setting the 'yRange = DateRange1d(4000,0)' does not invert the range.  Zero (0) is still at the bottom of the plot even if you invert the values (0, 4000).  It does invert with 'yRange = [4000, 0]' but the hover tool doesn't present a tooltip.

Comment: Did you update to Bokeh v1.0.4? The image above shows inverted range and tooltips showing canvas x + y

Comment: Not yet.  Seems the Admin is looking into that now.  Will advise.

Comment: Sorry, the y_range is indeed not inverted on my screenshot above. And when I specify the range like yRange = DataRange1d(start = 4000, end = 0) then the range is inverted but  hover doesn't work anymore. It is definitely a Bokeh issue: hover not working on inverted y_range

Comment: So my Pycharm is now at 1.0.4 for bokeh and as you indicated if I invert the axis the tool tip/hover tool does not work.  Do I need to submit a issue with GitLab?

Comment: I already did. This is a [Bokeh issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/8762). Should be solved in next release.

Comment: Great.  Was starting to write a issue.

Comment: Tony, do you have either a ticket/issue number for this problem?  Sorry, just saw it (#8762).  Many Thanks!

Comment: Just click on the link above (Bokeh issue). The issues has been already solved.